# Java library for quarter-of-the-year and week-of-the-year?

Tags: library, java

I am looking to support quarters and weeks as objects in my Java code.

I am aware that the troublesome old legacy date-time classes in Java have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. But I do not see any “Quarter” or “Week” classes amongst the classes such as `LocalDate` and `Instant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

Yes, there is such a library to represent:

- **Quarters**
  If you mean quarters # 1 = January-March, # 2 = April-June, and so on.
- **Weeks**
  If you mean weeks according to the [ISO 8601 standard week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), where week number one of the week-based-year contains the first Thursday of the calendar-year, starts on a Monday and runs through Sunday, for a total of 52 or 53 weeks per year.

In those definitions meet yours, then add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/index.html) library to your project.

Look at classes:

- [`Quarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html), and [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html)
- [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html)

## java.time

The java.time classes built into Java 8 & 9 offer limited support for week and year of a week-based-year.

### `IsoFields`

Use `get` method and pass one of the [`IsoFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html) constants. Call `get` on various classes such as `ZonedDateTime` and `LocalDate`.

```
myZonedDateTime.get( IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
myZonedDateTime.get( IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR )
```

### `DateTimeFormatter`

Also, the `DateTimeFormatter` class includes some formatting code for both  values week and week-based-year. You can put them together for ISO 8601 standard format of “yyyy-Www”.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-'W'ww" ) ;
String output = LocalDate.now().format( f );
```

> 2018-W39

For the full version of the standard format that appends the day-of-week as a digit 1-7 for Monday-Sunday, use the predefined constant, [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_WEEK_DATE ;  // yyyy-Www-d  For example: 2018-W39-7
String output = LocalDate.now().format( f );
```

> 2018-W39-7

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).